# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found

Tags: qt, debian

I'm getting

```
 qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
```

after a fresh installation of qt creator in Debian 9. Unfortunately, the solutions here tell me to do `ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` but `/usr/lib/qt/` doesn't even exist.

Comment: execute `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and execute your executable: `./your_executable`, what is the output?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0`

Comment: Instead of posting one line of code, please consider adding more of an explanation on why you recommend this and how it answers OP’s question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this two steps, it work for me with wireshark

```
$ sudo -s
# sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

and reboot for [more ...](https://blog.wireshark.org/2010/02/running-wireshark-as-you/)